# Read and save WP post meta field data from Gutenberg block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I used the code from [this article](https://css-tricks.com/managing-wordpress-metadata-in-gutenberg-using-a-sidebar-plugin/) as an example.
It is possible to read the data, but not to save it.

Code:

```js
const { Component, Fragment } = wp.element;

const {
  RichText,
  InspectorControls,
  PanelColorSettings,
  AlignmentToolbar,
  BlockControls,
} = wp.editor;

const { Button, PanelBody, SelectControl, TextControl } = wp.components;

const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;

const { withSelect, withDispatch } = wp.data;

class Inspector extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(...arguments);
  }
  render() {
    const backgroundColors = [
      { color: "#525252", name: "Черный" },
      { color: "#872d2d", name: "Акцентный красный" },
      { color: "#e49312", name: "Акцентный желтый" },
      { color: "#bab3a6", name: "Акцентный кремовый" },
    ];

    const fontSizeOptions = [
      { value: "14px", label: __("14px") },
      { value: "16px", label: __("16px") },
      { value: "18px", label: __("18px") },
      { value: "22px", label: __("22px") },
      { value: "28px", label: __("28px") },
    ];

    const paddingTopOptions = [
      { value: "0px", label: __("0px") },
      { value: "10px", label: __("10px") },
      { value: "25px", label: __("25px") },
      { value: "50px", label: __("50px") },
    ];

    const paddingBottomOptions = [
      { value: "0px", label: __("0px") },
      { value: "10px", label: __("10px") },
      { value: "25px", label: __("25px") },
      { value: "50px", label: __("50px") },
    ];

    const {
      setAttributes,
      attributes: { text_color, font_size, padding_top, padding_bottom },
    } = this.props;

    let PluginMetaFields = (props) => {
      return (
        <>
          <TextControl
            value={props.text_metafield}
            label={__("Text Meta", "textdomain")}
            onChange={(value) => props.onMetaFieldChange(value)}
          />
        </>
      );
    };
    PluginMetaFields = withSelect((select) => {
      return {
        text_metafield: select("core/editor").getEditedPostAttribute("meta")[
          "_myprefix_text_metafield"
        ],
      };
    })(PluginMetaFields);

    PluginMetaFields = withDispatch((dispatch) => {
      return {
        onMetaFieldChange: (value) => {
          dispatch("core/editor").editPost({
            meta: { _myprefix_text_metafield: value },
          });
        },
      };
    })(PluginMetaFields);

    return (
      <InspectorControls key="inspector">
        <PanelBody title={__("Настройки абзаца")}>
          <PanelColorSettings
            title={__("Цвет шрифта")}
            initialOpen={true}
            colorSettings={[
              {
                value: text_color,
                colors: backgroundColors,
                onChange: (value) => setAttributes({ text_color: value }),
                label: __("Цвет шрифта"),
              },
            ]}
          />
          <SelectControl
            label={__("Размер шрифта")}
            options={fontSizeOptions}
            value={font_size}
            onChange={(value) => this.props.setAttributes({ font_size: value })}
          />
          <SelectControl
            label={__("Отступ сверху")}
            options={paddingTopOptions}
            value={padding_top}
            onChange={(value) =>
              this.props.setAttributes({ padding_top: value })
            }
          />
          <SelectControl
            label={__("Отступ снизу")}
            options={paddingBottomOptions}
            value={padding_bottom}
            onChange={(value) =>
              this.props.setAttributes({ padding_bottom: value })
            }
          />
          <PluginMetaFields />
        </PanelBody>
      </InspectorControls>
    );
  }
}

class HeadlineBlock extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      attributes: {
        headline,
        text_color,
        font_size,
        padding_top,
        padding_bottom,
        alignment,
      },
      setAttributes,
    } = this.props;

    const onChangeAlignment = (newAlignment) => {
      this.props.setAttributes({
        alignment: newAlignment === undefined ? "none" : newAlignment,
      });
    };

    return [
      <Inspector {...{ setAttributes, ...this.props }} />,

      <div>
        {
          <BlockControls>
            <AlignmentToolbar value={alignment} onChange={onChangeAlignment} />
          </BlockControls>
        }
        <RichText
          tagName="p"
          placeholder={__("Текст...")}
          keepPlaceholderOnFocus
          value={headline}
          formattingControls={["bold", "italic", "strikethrough", "link"]}
          className={"font-" + font_size + " post-desc__p-text"}
          style={{
            color: text_color,
            textAlign: alignment,
          }}
          onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ headline: value })}
        />
      </div>,
    ];
  }
}

registerBlockType("amm-custom-block/test-block", {
  title: __("Тест блок"),
  icon: "shield",
  category: "AMM",
  attributes: {
    headline: {
      type: "string",
    },
    alignment: {
      type: "string",
      default: "none",
    },
    text_color: {
      type: "string",
      default: "#525252",
    },
    font_size: {
      type: "string",
      default: "14px",
    },
    padding_top: {
      type: "string",
      default: "50px",
    },
    padding_bottom: {
      type: "string",
      default: "0px",
    },
  },
  edit: HeadlineBlock,
  save: function (props) {
    const {
      attributes: {
        headline,
        text_color,
        font_size,
        padding_top,
        padding_bottom,
        alignment,
      },
    } = props;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {headline && !!headline.length && (
          <RichText.Content
            tagName="p"
            className={"font-" + font_size + " post-desc__p-text"}
            style={{
              color: text_color,
              paddingTop: padding_top,
              paddingBottom: padding_bottom,
              textAlign: alignment,
            }}
            value={headline}
          />
        )}
      </Fragment>
    );
  },
});
```

So far just added a text field to the block and am trying to read and save the data.
With reading everything is OK, but saving the data does not work and there are no errors.

Any idea why this is happening?

sorry english is not a native language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta field **_myprefix_text_metafield** is a protected field as it starts with a "_" (underscore). This is why you can read the value in withSelect() but not save over it withDispatch() without passing auth_callback.

To save to a protected field, the [auth_callback is required](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/metabox/meta-block-2-register-meta/), eg:

```
<?php
register_post_meta( 'post', '_myprefix_text_metafield', array(
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'single' => true,
    'type' => 'string',
    'auth_callback' => function() {
        return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
    }) 
);
?>
```

There is an example in the tutorial you are following:
https://css-tricks.com/managing-wordpress-metadata-in-gutenberg-using-a-sidebar-plugin/#post-291605

Alternatively, if your meta field is not required to be protected/private: re-register your meta field as **myprefix_text_metafield** (no underscore in the name and no auth_callback) and your current code will work, eg:

```
<?php
register_post_meta( 'post', 'myprefix_text_metafield', array(
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'single' => true,
    'type' => 'string'
);
?>
```